# Date after another date in symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, date, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I have a form that contain 2 dates: start date(datedebut) and end date(datefin). 
 I want the end date to be always after the start date. How can i do that?

My form type:

```
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('datedebut',DateType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+20),
            ))
            ->add('datefin',DateType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+20),
            ))
            ->add('nbplaces')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bridge\TravelBundle\Entity\Reservation'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'Bridge_TravelBundle_Reservation';
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the question it's not so clear and you should update your question to specify exactly what you want to achieve (_and adding more server/front code if it is necessary_). Do you want to check the `datefin` value after form submit or what? Read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed and on-topic question.

Comment: This isn't a server side thing to-do, you'll want to update the second date input using Javascript but then also validate it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these kind of tasks are solved by adding validation constraints to check if value of one field is greater then the other. Implement `callback` validation constraint as stated in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html You can also create your custom class constraint validator and place validation logic there: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

This way whenever a user tries to submit value of `datefin` which is less than selected value of `datedebut` he will see a validation error and the form will not be processed.

After that you can always add some javascript code that will filter available dates in  `datefin` field after value in `datedebut` field is changed.

Also you can use dynamic form modification to render the second date field (and filter its available dates on server side) only if value of the first one is submitted. Check this out: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Callback Validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) for this. Injected into that callback is a `ExecutionContextInterface` by which you can access the form, and thus other form params.

Here's an example:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;

// …

$builder
    ->add('start', 'datetime', 
        'constraints' => [
            new Constraints\NotBlank(),
            new Constraints\DateTime(),
        ],
    ])
    ->add('stop', 'datetime', [
        'constraints' => [
            new Constraints\NotBlank(),
            new Constraints\DateTime(),
            new Constraints\Callback(function($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                $start = $context->getRoot()->getData()['start'];
                $stop = $object;

                if (is_a($start, \DateTime::class) && is_a($stop, \DateTime::class)) {
                    if ($stop->format('U') - $start->format('U') < 0) {
                        $context
                            ->buildViolation('Stop must be after start')
                            ->addViolation();
                    }
                }
            }),
        ],
    ]);
```